# Import Framework only for one device type

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, frameworks

In my **universal iOS** app written in **Objective-C**, I use the Facebook SDK, which unfortunately **takes a lot of space** and import it using the following statement at the top of my file:

```
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>
```

As I only require this for the iPhone part of the app, I'm wondering whether it would be maybe possible to **import the Framework only if the app is installed on an iPhone** to save my iPad users some storage. Is there any way to realise that?

Comment: Curious - why would you only need the Facebook SDK when the app is run on the iPhone but not when run on an iPad?

Comment: It's because I do not really use it for the iPhone, but for the  Watch ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be done because the inclusion and use of the Facebook SDK is done at compile/link time. But for a universal app, the detection of the device is done at runtime. At that point there is just the one binary that already has the SDK built into it.